# jQuery add empty label tags next to every radio button or checkbox

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button, jquery-selectors, addition

I need a simple jQuery code that will add an empty label tag next to every radio button or checkbox

So for example:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').next().add("<label for="radio"></label>");
$('input[type="checkbox"]').next().add("<label for="checkbox"></label>");
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').after("<label for='radio'></label>");
$('input[type="checkbox"]').after("<label for='checkbox'></label>");
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to accomplish this.  Also, you'll want the `for` of your label to be the `id` to which it refers.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
     var cb = $(this);
     cb.after($("<label />")
                .attr("for", cb.attr("id")) );
});
```

You said you wanted empty labels, but just in case, if you want the labels to display the value of the checkbox they're next to, this should do that:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
     var cb = $(this);
     cb.after($("<label />")
                .attr("for", cb.attr("id"))
                .text(cb.val()) );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the jQuery function `.after()`

```
$('input[type="radio"]').after('<label for="radio"></label>');
$('input[type="checkbox"]').after('<label for="checkbox"></label>');
```

But, if you want the label to target the correct element, you will need to do this:

```
$('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]').each( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr( "id" );
    $(this).after('<label for="' + id + '"></label>');
} );
```

You need to put the id of the element in the `for` attribute of the label tag

Comment: need to change the the double quote to single quote "<label for='radio'></label>"

Comment: It did not work, it even corrupted the other JavaScript on that page.

Comment: @user1090389 Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Hhf/) showing it works no problem ;)  If it didn't work for you, it is because you added it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':radio, :checkbox').each(function () {
    $(this).before('<label for="' + this.id + '"></label>');
});
```